# When is the extension $L(S)/L$ Galois and totally ramified?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, local-fields

Let $L$ be a finite extension of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ with uniformizer $\pi$. Let us consider the polynomial ring $L[x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_l]$ in $l$-variables and $f_1, f_2, \dotsc, f_m \in L[x_1, \dotsc, x_l]$.

Let $S$ be the set of simultaneous zeros of the following system
\begin{align}
f_1(x_1,\dotsc,x_l) & {}=0 \\
\vdots & \\
f_m(x_1, \dotsc,x_l) & {}=0.
\end{align}
Then, clearly every element in $S$ is a point in an affine $l$-space over some field extension of $L$. So the *coordinates of each points* in $S$ generate a field extension. i.e., consider the field extension $L(S)$ obtained by *adjoining the coordinates of each solution* to $S$.
So it looks like $L(S)$ is a subfield of $\bar L$.

**Questions:**

1. Is (or when is) the extension $L(S)/L$ Galois?
2. When is $L(S)/L$ totally ramified?

---

**My Effort:**

1. $L(S)$ is an algebraic extension of $L$ because its elements are algebraic over $L$. In this multivariable case, we don't need separability of the roots/solutions because we are taking the coordinates only. Also two solutions $(x_1, \dotsc,x_l)$ and $(x_1',\dotsc, x_l')$ may have some common coordinates, say, $x_i=x_i'$ but this doesn't affect because both give the same extension, so we will take just one of the coordinates.

Let $L'$ be the Galois closure of $L(S)$ over $L$ i.e, the smallest field containing $L(S)$ that is Galois over $L$. Take any $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(L'/L)$ and a solution $s \in S$, then its Galois conjugate $\sigma(s)$ is also a solution i.e., $\sigma(s) \in S$. So $\sigma(s)=t$ for some $t \in S$. So by **restricting** the domain of $\sigma$ to $L(S)$, we have $$\sigma(L(S)) \subset L(S).$$ Next, since $\sigma$ induces a permutation on $S$, then for each $\alpha \in L(S)$, $\sigma^{-1}(\alpha)=\beta$ for some $\beta \in L(S)$. So $\alpha=\sigma(\beta)$ and so we have $$L(S) \subset \sigma(L(S)).$$

Therefore, $\sigma(L(S))=L(S)$.  Thus each $\sigma\rvert_{L(S)}$ is an automorphism.  So it seems that $L(S)$ is Galois over $L$.

Am I correct? Am I missing something?

Any discussion please.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128786/discussion-on-question-by-mathlearner-when-are-the-extensions-ls-k-and-ls).

Comment: The work you do seems mostly fine, aside from some strange terminology (you seem to say that $L(S)$ is a proper subfield of $\bar L$ to mean just that it is a subfield—in fact there's some argument in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128786/discussion-on-question-by-mathlearner-when-are-the-extensions-ls-k-and-ls) that it's often all of $\bar L$; and you say that a permutation acts transitively on a set to mean just that it is, well, a permutation of that set), but this does not seem to be a research-level question.

Comment: @LSpice, thanks, I have excluded the word `proper`. But in Chat section, as you said, $L(S)=\bar L$ was in previous setting, slightly different. I am not sure whether in the current setting $L(S)$ is equal to $\bar L$ or not. Second, regarding the level of the question, I want to define a map  $Gal(L(S)/L) \to (\mathcal{O}_K/\pi^n \mathcal{O}_K)^{\times}, \ n \geq 1$, once I know $Gal(L(S)/L)$ is Galois. Any help here ?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want; your current question doesn't mention any [such map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402142/when-is-the-extension-ls-l-galois-and-totally-ramified#comment1028433_402142).  Of course there is a trivial map $\operatorname{Gal}(L(S)/L) \to (\mathcal O_K/\pi^n\mathcal O_K)^\times$, so probably some conditions need to be imposed. \\ You have also kept the language "$\operatorname{Gal}(L'/L)$ acts transitively on $S$" where you seem just to mean "$\operatorname{Gal}(L'/L)$ acts on $S$".

Comment: @LSpice, If I want to define a group homomorphism $f:~Gal(L(S)/L) \to (\mathcal{O}_K/\pi^n\mathcal{O}_K)^{\times}$ which becomes injective. I am not sure how to do it. But I think we need to use the action of $Gal(L(S)/L)$ on $S$ to define the homomorphism.  Assume that the zero set $S$ has $\mathcal{O}_L$-module structure. Now, set  $f(\sigma)=\theta$ such that $\sigma(s)=\theta * s$ for $s \in S$, $\theta \in \mathcal{O}_L$. Here $*$ is the action of $\mathcal{O}_L$ on the zero set $S$.  Does this make $f$ a group homomorphism ?

Comment: It's not clear to me why a $\theta$ as in [your definition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402142/when-is-the-extension-ls-l-galois-and-totally-ramified#comment1028445_402142) should exist, nor why it should be independent of $s$; and it seems to me unlikely that $S$ should carry such a module structure.  If all these obstructions vanish, then $f$ is clearly a homomorphism, since $\sigma\tau(s) = \sigma(\theta_\tau)\sigma(s) = \theta_\tau\theta_\sigma s$ for all $s \in S$ and all $\sigma, \tau \in \operatorname{Gal}(L(S)/L)$.

Comment: $\textbf{Correction:}$ In some of my above comments, I meant $\mathcal{O}_L$ not   $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: @LSpice, I just assumed $S$ has $\mathcal{O}_L$-module structure in order to define the map, as you said in your earliar comment to 'impose some conditions'. What do you mean by $\theta_{\tau}$ ? Do you mean $\tau$ acting on $\theta$ i.e., $\tau(\theta)$ ? Finally, Is there any other way to define a homomorphism between the groups ?

Comment: No; I mean that, even if all [the obstructions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402142/when-is-the-extension-ls-l-galois-and-totally-ramified#comment1028454_402142) vanish, still you'll get different $\theta$'s for different Galois-group elements.  I was writing $\theta_\sigma$ and $\theta_\tau$ for the $\theta$'s associated to $\sigma$ and $\tau$.

Comment: And, although of course a (very) special case is a reasonable starting point, by "[some conditions need to be imposed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402142/when-is-the-extension-ls-l-galois-and-totally-ramified#comment1028440_402142)" I meant:  how should a conjectural $f$ behave?  (Why do you want it?  Why do you expect it to exist?)  Anyway, if $L(S)/L$ is totally ramified then you have some such map, for some $n$ depending on the 'sauvagerie', but I see no reason $n$ should be the number of variables.

Comment: @LSpice, sorry, I did another mistake. When I said $\mathcal{O}_L/\pi^n \mathcal{O}_L$, I  just mean $n$ is any natural number (not the number of variables). I changed the notation in question